# Unmet dependencies errors after upgrading from 18 to 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I recently upgraded from ubuntu 18 to ubuntu 20.04, afaik everyhing works as normal, my websites are still running as always, only thing is when I try to install new libraries I get unmet dependencies error:

For example

```
ubuntuname@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install php7.3-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lxd : Depends: lxd-client (= 3.0.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.2) but 1:0.9 is to be installed
 lxd-client : Depends: lxd (>= 1:0.9) but 3.0.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 is to be installed
 php7.3-dev : Depends: libpcre2-dev (>= 10.30) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: php7.3-cli (>= 7.3.33-11+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 7.3.14-6+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
              Depends: php7.3-common (= 7.3.33-11+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but 7.3.14-6+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
              Depends: shtool but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libtool (>= 2.4.6-0.1~) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: pkg-php-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Or

```
ubuntuname@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install pkg-config libmagickwand-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
pkg-config is already the newest version (0.29.1-0ubuntu4).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmagickwand-dev : Depends: libmagickwand-6.q16-dev but it is not going to be installed
 lxd : Depends: lxd-client (= 3.0.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.2) but 1:0.9 is to be installed
 lxd-client : Depends: lxd (>= 1:0.9) but 3.0.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Any idea what could be wrong?